# Using HTML/JS or another web solution to render a twirling ribbon

Tags: javascript, html, 3d

Any thoughts on creating a fluid/flowing ribbon for a website effect?

I'm open to any ideas. Ideally I could do this simply with html and some js library, but I'm open to suggestions for doing this with flash also. Any links to tutorials or examples would be greatly appreciated as well.

Thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at HTML 5 as an option as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) is a popular JavaScript animation library which is a port of the [Processing visualization language](http://processing.org/).  There are some pretty impressive demos on the site, including [this one of a snake which follows your mouse](http://processingjs.org/learning/custom/snake).  I could imagine taking that and modifying it to be a twirling ribbon.   Also, check out [HasCanvas](http://hascanvas.com/) for 350+ more demos - I'm betting that someone has made something similar to what you're looking for - [here is kind of a neat ribbon-y effect I saw on the first page](http://hascanvas.com/randomisedfrequency).